# How to ignore annoying users?

Tags: support, users

Most internet sites have the ability to maintain a personal ignore list. This makes utterances of annoying people invisible for the user feeling annoyed. I like this feature very much, because it simplifies my life.

Where can I define an ignore list for unix.stackexchange.com?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3353/270345

Comment: @muru I can not remove the `status-declined` tag.

Comment: Obviously not. That's a mod tag. The SE people have spoken, and that request is declined.

Comment: If there's a comment that you feel [isn't nice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) or needs moderator intervention, then flag it.

Comment: @JeffSchaller "moderator intervention" means censorship. I like to avoid being annoyed without asking for censorship.

Comment: Censorship: the suppression or prohibition of any parts of books, films, news, etc. that are considered obscene, politically unacceptable, or a threat to security.  (I was going to comment on the applicability or inapplicability of this term to the discussion, but I think I shall let it stand for itself.)

Answer (score 8):

**Social interaction** sites have ignore lists. Stack Exchange is not a social interaction site. There is no ignore list on Wikipedia. There is no ignore list on Stack Exchange either.

If somebody is [not nice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice), then [flag](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) the offending post or comment to let moderators know. Do not respond in kind.

Stack Exchange *chat* is a social interaction medium and it does have an ignore 
list (click on the user name then on “ignore this user”).

Comment: Your definition of "not nice" does not include narrow-minded self-opinionated nags, because it is a subjective judgment, which requires a subjective solution. And that exactly is an ignore list. It is a personal decision based on subjective reasons. Although you may wish SO may be no social interaction site, my social interaction on this side made me thinking about someone else he is a narrow-minded self-opinionated nag. And nothing you say will change my opinion. And I do not want to talk to you or anybody else about him. I just do not want to see his postings anymore. It could be so easy.